# Resize only when there is not enough horizontal space to avoid horizontal scroll bar

Tags: css

Image on the left, text on the right. Image size is unknown. I want to display the image in its original size. I want the text at least 10-character wide (i.e., not too narrow).

If I resize the browser window to make it narrow, when the text cannot become narrower, the page shows horizontal scroll bar. Can I at this point reduce the image width instead? Again, image size is not fixed. I wonder if this can be done with CSS only, or if I use JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .item {
            display: flex;
        }

        .rightText {
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-left: 1em;
            min-width: 10em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.asahicom.jp/and/data/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1-1.jpg"/>
        <div class="rightText">
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.item {
    display: flex;
}

.item img{
   max-width:calc(100% - 11em);
}

.rightText {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 1em;
    min-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.asahicom.jp/and/data/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1-1.jpg"/>
        <div class="rightText">
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works almost as I expected, but there is one weird thing. If I keep narrowing the window, at some point, the image's width stops shrinking but the height stops the same, changing the aspect ratio. Can we prevent that to always keep the aspect ratio?

Comment: Found a way. Add `object-fit: scale-down;` to img. By default, it's centred, and adding `object-position:0% 0%;` made it align to the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Change the width and height to something you feel looks good as a starter and see how it works, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      img{
       max-width:100%;
      }
        .item {
            display: flex;
        }
        .rightText {
            min-width:10ch;
            margin-left: 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="imgone">
           <img src="https://www.asahicom.jp/and/data/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/1-1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="rightText">
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
            きこえるかしらひずめの音ゆるやかな丘をぬってかけてくる馬車
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Is this what you had in mind?